# Laravel 5.0 php artisan make:model ModelName auto creating migration class

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Laravel's command:
php artisan make:model ModelName

automatically creating creating migration class with the Model Name. Is there are way that we could pass additional parameters to the make:model command so that it ignores creating migration class?

Answer (score 14):

You should write this command:
`php artisan make:model modelName --no-migration`

Artisan CLI providers a help message for all commands.
For instance `php artisan help make:model` shows a list of available cli arguments for the `make:model` command.

**UPDATE [2015]**:
Starting 5.1, migrations are not automatically created anymore. You can use the flag `--migration` to generate one.

Comment: The "--no-migration" option does not exist.